# Bash store IPs as variable

Tags: bash

I'm working with a lot of IPs for various machines and I need to SSH into them regularly. I would like to store the IPs in variables that way if they ever change I only need to make the change in one place instead of all over my script. How do I put a number like `10.0.0.1` into a variable?

I've tried

```
IP=$("10.0.0.1")
echo $IP
```

This doesn't seem to work. Anyone know of a good simple way to do this? I get command not found so I'm guessing bash doesn't like the dots...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
IP=10.0.0.1
echo $IP
```

The syntax you have used

```
IP=$("10.0.0.1")
```

is what is known as [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_03_04_04).  The shell attempts to run the bash command contained within the `$()`, and to store its output in the variable IP.

Thus the "*command not found*" message was due to the fact that "10.0.0.1" is not a command that the shell recognizes.

Comment: Sometimes I just overthink the small stuff. Thanks! It won't let me accept the answer for another few minutes

Comment: To add to the answer: In order to store multiple IPs, you can use bash array. e.g. `IP=("10.0.0.1" "10.0.0.2")`